# Taking random value from array - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, random

I've got array od values, and I want to take random from it. This is my code:

```
var bonus1='Opony zimowe';
var bonus2='Alarm';
var bonus3 = 'Bagażnik';
var bonus4 = 'Relingi';
var bonus5 = 'Box na narty';
var bonusy = [bonus1, bonus2, bonus3, bonus4, bonus5];
var pickBonus= bonusy[Math.floor(Math.random() * bonusy.length)];
```

But it doesn't show random value (Its always console.log - 'Alarm'):

[image: Console Output]

What is wrong?

Comment: your code works, you're just printing the same `pickBonus` value over and over again... you need to run through the `Math.random()` part, to receive a new value.

Comment: @tipsfedora same here

Comment: Works fine for me. Perhaps there's a problem elsewhere in your code?

Answer (score 10):

From your screenshot it appears that you are basically trying to print the same value multiple times expecting a different value.

It won't work, **you need to get the random value again** from the array every time. Make it into a function

```
 var pickBonus= () => bonusy[Math.floor(Math.random() * bonusy.length)];
```

And now invoke it as

```
console.log( pickBonus() );
console.log( pickBonus() );
console.log( pickBonus() );
console.log( pickBonus() );
```

**Demo**

```js
var bonus1='Opony zimowe';
var bonus2='Alarm';
var bonus3 = 'Bagażnik';
var bonus4 = 'Relingi';
var bonus5 = 'Box na narty';
var bonusy = [bonus1, bonus2, bonus3, bonus4, bonus5];
var pickBonus= () => bonusy[Math.floor(Math.random() * bonusy.length)];

console.log( pickBonus() );
console.log( pickBonus() );
console.log( pickBonus() );
console.log( pickBonus() );
```

Answer (score 2):

`pickBonus` should be a function and not a variable in your case.

Then you can run this type of code and always get random values:

```js
var bonus1 = 'Opony zimowe';
var bonus2 = 'Alarm';
var bonus3 = 'Bagażnik';
var bonus4 = 'Relingi';
var bonus5 = 'Box na narty';
var bonusy = [bonus1, bonus2, bonus3, bonus4, bonus5];

function pickBonus() {
  return bonusy[Math.floor(Math.random() * bonusy.length)];
}

console.log(pickBonus());
console.log(pickBonus());
console.log(pickBonus());
console.log(pickBonus());
```

Answer (score 1):

replace the last line

`var pickBonus= bonusy[Math.floor(Math.random() * (bonusy.length-1)) + 1]`

and wrap the whole code in a function to populate new `pickBonus` value in each function call